# How to use StyleCop checkin policy with VS2012 TFS2010

Tags: visual-studio-2012, checkin-policy

I am using Visual Studio 2012 with TFS 2010, I want to use StyleCop checkin policy but it doesn't  work. I have installed StyleCop, StyleCop Check-In Policy for TFS 2010 and Team Foundation Power Tools 2010 on server  and client,  still no benefit.

Comment: Can you define "doesn't work"? Can you specify the policy in Team Explorer? Is it not firing? Does it work in VS2010? You should not have to install anything on the server, since checkin policies are handled client side... Also check out this blog post: http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2012/03/using-existing-check-in-policies-with.html

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an older post but I just released a check-in policy for Visual Studio 2013. I don't know if you already using VS2013 but take a look at this extension. If you want VS2012 support, you can add an issue. If there are enough votes I will add support for it.
https://stylecopcheckinpolicy.codeplex.com/